# Javascript iPhone Scroll Effect in an iFrame / Javascript Mouse Acceleration

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, iframe, acceleration

I'm trying to recreate the iPhone flick / scroll event in a window using JavaScript.

Starting with JQuery, I'm measuring the mouse's acceleration and offset during click - drag - release events using a timer:

```
var MouseY = {

    init: function(context) {
        var self = this;
        self._context = context || window
        self._down = false;
        self._now = 0;
        self._last = 0;
        self._offset = 0;
        self._timer = 0;
        self._acceleration = 0;

        $(self._context).mousedown(function() {self._down = true;});
        $(self._context).mouseup(function() {self._down = false;});
        $(self._context).mousemove(function(e) {self.move(e);});

    },

    move: function(e) {
        var self = this;
        self._timer++;
        self._last = self._now;
        self._now = e.clientY + window.document.body.scrollTop;
        self._offset = self._now - self._last;
        self._acceleration = self._offset / self._timer;
    },

    reset: function() {
        this._offset = 0;
        this._acceleration = 0;
        this._timer = 0;
    }
};


$(function() {
    MouseY.init();
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#info').html(
            '_acceleration:' + MouseY._acceleration + '<br />' +
            '_now:' + MouseY._now + '<br />' +
            '_offset:' + MouseY._offset + '<br />' +
            '_timer:' + MouseY._timer + '<br />'
        );
        MouseY.reset();
    }, 10);

});
```

Now the problem is translating that acceleration into screen movement - are there any algorithms (easing?) or animation libraries that could help me out on this? (I've looked into JQuery's .animate() but I'm unsure of how to apply it continuously during the drag events!

**Update - final solution here:**

http://johnboxall.github.com/iphone.html

Comment: With the help of the answer I've more or less solved this one:

http://johnboxall.github.com/iphone.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hit up this link for the full explanation of one approach that seems to be what you're looking for.

http://www.faqts.com/knowledge_base/view.phtml/aid/14742/fid/53

Here's an excerpt:

> This handler then sets up event
>   capture for mouse movement and stores 
>   mouse cursor positions in variables
>   mouseX and mouseY. It then starts  the
>   timer monitorMouse() which measures
>   mouse cursor speed by sampling  the
>   values in these variables at regular
>   intervals. The variables  mouseLeft
>   and mouseTop hold each samplings mouse
>   positions and the  sampling rate is
>   set to 100 milliseconds in the
>   variable  monitor.timerDelay.

And some of the author's code:

```
nn4 = (document.layers)? true:false;
mouseLeft = mouseTop = mouseX = mouseY = 0;
monitor = {
    timerDelay:100,
    moveLimit:2,
    sampleLimit:10
};

function startMonitor(thisText) {
    if (!tip) return;
    toolTipText = thisText;
    writeTooltip(toolTipText);

    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
    document.onmousemove = function (evt) {
        mouseX = evt.pageX;
        mouseY = evt.pageY;
        return true;
    }
    monitorMouse();
}

function stopMonitor() {
    if (!tip) return;
    hideTooltip();
        if (monitor.timer) {
        clearTimeout(monitor.timer);
        monitor.timer = null;
    }
    document.releaseEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
    document.onmousemove = null;
    monitor.slowSamples = 0;
}

function monitorMouse() {
    if (Math.abs(mouseX - mouseLeft)   > monitor.moveLimit
        || Math.abs(mouseY - mouseTop) > monitor.moveLimit)
    {
        monitor.slowSamples = 0;
    }
    else if (++monitor.slowSamples > monitor.sampleLimit) {
        showTooltip();
        return;
    }
    mouseLeft = mouseX;
    mouseTop  = mouseY;
    monitor.timer = setTimeout("monitorMouse()",monitor.timerDelay);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's what I found when looking for kinetic/momentum scrolling libraries:

- [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll)
- [Zynga Scroller](https://github.com/zynga/scroller)
- [Overscroll](http://www.azoffdesign.com/plugins/js/overscroll)
- [TouchScroll](http://uxebu.com/blog/2010/09/15/touchscroll-0-2-first-alpha-available/)
- [jScrollTouch](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jScrollTouch)

Comment: amazing. life saver + AAA++ repped

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the jQuery plugin named overscroll:
http://www.azoffdesign.com/overscroll ([GitHub page](https://github.com/azoff/Overscroll))