# Drag to Scroll In iframe

Tags: jquery, html, mootools, iscroll4

All

I want to make iPhone style drag to scroll functionality in **iframe**.
This is my sample code

```
<iframe src="http://www.css-tricks.com" width="360" height="500" id="dynFrame"></iframe>​
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ajaypatel_aj/PgujJ/

You can see here the vertical scrollbar to scroll page, i want to scroll page by draggin Up or Down side.

I have tried iScroll but it didn't work for iframe. Also trying from this

1. https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll
2. http://mootools.net/demos/?demo=Drag.Scroll

Thanks In Advanced.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379917/javascript-iphone-scroll-effect-in-an-iframe-javascript-mouse-acceleration

Comment: @kachar I know the iPhone style scroll, what i want is to use it in iFrame